# C#: Setting child class to null on parents dispose?

Tags: c#, .net

Is my implementation of dispose correct? In this question I'm sort of asking 1 question but about 1 topic to understand it better.

- Do I need to set lists, dictionarys and any type of collection to
  null on dispose?
- Do I need to clear collections on dispose?
- Do I need    to set child class to null on dispose?

Take this code for example..

```
public class ParentClass : IDisposable
{
    private readonly ChildClass;

    public ParentClass()
    {
        ChildClass = new ParentClass();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        ChildClass.Dispose();
        ChildClass = null;
    }
}

public class ChildClass : IDisposable
{
    private Dictionary<int> myIds;

    public ChildClass()
    {
        myIds = new Dictionary<int>();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        myIds.Clear();
        myIds = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: with the classes you are showing, not only you can leave empty the Dispose methods, but actually the classes should not be `IDisposable` at all

Comment: This code is wrong in a number of ways; please don't post confusingly wrong code. eg: you have a field of type ChildClass with no name, you're assigning an instance of ParentClass to what I presume is a field of type ChildClass even though there is no relationship between the classes, and so on. If you're asking about how to implement dispose correctly in a case where you have a disposable class inheriting from a disposable base class then this is not that question.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to all your questions is *no*. .NET programs use managed code, which means the platform will clean up all these objects for you.

Now, if you access an unmanaged resource such as a file, database, etc. That's when you need to use `IDisposable` to ensure that any unmanaged resources get cleaned up in a timely manner.

But things like `Dictionary<>` will clean up themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Whether members should be set to null in Dispose() can be answered in different ways. It's (as said in many other answers - see "Related" on the right) only necessary for members that are on itself disposable.

First, it's obviously only possible to set a member to null in Dispose() if it is *not* declared as readonly. Making them not readonly just because of this is probably not a good design pattern. If you *do* set it to null after dispose, you also have to check for null before doing so, because you must always be able to call Dispose() multiple times without side effects or exceptions. Setting a member to null also helps in preventing that you accidentally use the object again after dispose (because accessing the member will cause an exception).